# How to log boot messages?

Tags: boot, 9.10, logging, 8.10

I'm trying to check the boot log messages in the file `/var/log/boot` on Ubuntu 8.10 & 9.10 and I found it empty with the message `(Nothing has been logged yet.)`. The `bootlogd` service is running at the startup.

I changed the file `vim /etc/default/bootlogd`

```
# Run bootlogd at startup ?
BOOTLOGD_ENABLE=No

Change No to Yes:

# Run bootlogd at startup ?
BOOTLOGD_ENABLE=Yes
```

Comment: This is schwon by me, too.
Do you have tried with `dmesg` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, me too. 
AFAIK, /var/log/dmesg has the boot messages. 
The program bootlog copies all strings sent to the /dev/console device to /var/log/boot AFTER the daemon is initialized. Messages from kernel booting are in dmesg.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is relevant, but the following page has a lower-case "y" in the "yes"

http://wiki.debian.org/bootlogd